# Wordpress Contact Form 7 Radio-Button Conditional Redirect

Tags: wordpress, redirect, radio-button, conditional-statements, contact-form-7

I've seen a few questions similar to this on here, but no working answers, etc.

I have a Contact 7 form with a radio button with four options, which of 4 states you reside in.  I need for when the form is submitted for it to redirect to that states page.

I have tried a number of different options, and a few have kind of worked... like this is what I currently have in the 'Additional Settings' area in Contact Form 7...

```
on_sent_ok: "var Iso = $("input[name=your-city]:checked").val() ; if(Iso == '1' ){ location = 'example.com/city2'; } else if (Iso == '2' ){ location = 'example.com/city2'; } else if (Iso == '3' ){ location = 'example.com/city3'; } else { location = 'example.com/city4'; }"
```

Obviously the URL's are full url's in my code... Problem is it's always going to /city4 no matter what is selected.  I've heard this is because by the time it's sent it's not sending back the correct info, but how would I go about making this work then?

Answer (score 0):

Hello how are you doing so I was looking for same thing and with help of your code i found solution

```
on_sent_ok:" 
  var utah = $("input[name=utah]:checked").val();
  var addiction = $("input[name=addiction]:checked").val();
  var discharged = $("input[name=discharged]:checked").val();
  if (utah == 'Yes' && addiction == 'Yes' && discharged == 'Yes'){
    location = 'example.com/city2'; 
  } else {
    location = 'example.com/city4';
  }
"
```

I used this code for my solution and it works.. In this i created three radiobuttons so if all are selected to yes then city 2 page load otherwise another page